# HOW TO ROTATE IMAGE in circular path

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-graphics

I want to `rotate image` (arrow) in circular path in `coreGraphics` like this image. in circular path.

input image:

[image: Arrow image]

output  after rotation:

[image: Rotate arrow in CoreGraphics iOS]

Comment: Show your code. what you have tried?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wLs5vbfL

Comment: I have call this function to rotate the image                                                            
  [self rotateImage:leafImage angle:archAngle+width/2 row:row ];//context:context];

Comment: self.imageview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return rotated image

```
- (UIImage *)rotateImage:(UIImage *)image onDegrees:(float)degrees
{
    CGFloat rads = M_PI * degrees / 180;
    float newSide = MAX([image size].width, [image size].height);
    CGSize size =  CGSizeMake(image.size.width, newSide);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, image.size.width, newSide/2);
    CGContextRotateCTM(ctx, rads);
    CGRect r = CGRectMake(0,-[image size].height/2,image.size.width,image. size.height);
    [image drawInRect:r];
    UIImage *i = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return i;
}

    UIImage *arrowRotated180  = [self rotateImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrowImage"] onDegrees:180];

    UIImage *arrowRotated90  = [self rotateImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrowImage"] onDegrees:90];
```

Comment: great this is what i was looking for (y)

Answer (score 0):

Put three images and rotate 2 & 3 image as follow.

```
imageview2.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/4);

imageview3.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
```

Hope this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

try UIcollectionview it worked my case .

Comment: this one has worked but i am unable to add the action for touch event through it